# Laravel: Check if data is integer on controller

Tags: php, laravel

How can I check if one input have integer value?

For example:

```
if ($request->input('public') == ¿int?){

}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

Comment: you can use is_int().

Answer (score 30):

You should try this:

```
if (is_int($request->input('public'))){


}
```

**OR**

```
if (is_numeric($request->input('public'))){


}
```

Comment: is_int() does not work in Lumen 6+ for inputs. It always says false, only is_numeric() works, but that does not have the same functionality

Answer (score 8):

```
filter_var($request->input('public'), FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false
```

because:

- is_int() is true for 12 but isn't for "12"
- is_numerric() is true for 12.12312323

Answer (score 1):

Use `is_int`:

```
$number = $request->input('public');

if (is_int($number)) {
   dd('number is an integer');
} else {
   dd('number is not an integer');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Data taken from the input is always a string.

Use Laravel validation to check if the data from the input is integer or number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ctype_digit](https://www.php.net/ctype_digit)

```
<?php
$cadenas = array('1820.20', '10002', 'wsl!12');
foreach ($cadenas as $caso_prueba) {
    if (ctype_digit($caso_prueba)) {
        echo "La cadena $caso_prueba consiste completamente de dígitos.\n";
    } else {
        echo "La cadena $caso_prueba no consiste completamente de dígitos.\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use shorthand if:

```
$isInteger = (is_int($request->input('public'))) ? true : false;
```

Comment: Using the ternary operator like this is redundant because is_int() already only resolves to true or false.